# How to read a ply file with only one intensity using pyhton

Tags: python, point-clouds, open3d, ply-file-format

I have a number of ply point clouds with only one intensity, i.e. [x y z intensity]. I plan to read them with open3d, but I can only read in the positions with the regular method. Is there a suitable way to do this with intensity?

```
path = './example.ply'
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(path,format='ply')

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([pcd])
```

Comment: What happens when you try your existing code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: I found that the ply file read by open3d does not have an intensity, only colours, points, normals. so is there a way to read intensities? Tnanks!

Comment: I can't understand. How do you expect to read intensity from the file, if the file does not contain intensity? What should "intensity" **mean**?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, but my ply file actually contains xyz and a column of intensities, but I can't find a way to read these ply files, the common ones seem to only read xyzrgb or just xyz. thanks!

Comment: open3d don't support XYZD files, so it will discard the intensity values.